# use shiftIn and shiftOut with attiny85

Tags: c++, attiny

I want my Attiny85 to communicate with another attiny85.
one attiny should send a message to my other attiny. When he receives the correct message he should turn one led on. Just a very simple test scatch.
I don't know why but the led never turns on.

Here is my code:

1st attiny85:

```
int clk_pin = 4,
    data_pin = 3,
    led = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(clk_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(data_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  byte incoming = shiftIn(data_pin, clk_pin, LSBFIRST);

  if (incoming == 2)
  {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

2nd attiny:

```
int clk_pin = 0,
    data_pin = 1;

void setup(){
  pinMode(clk_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(data_pin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  byte test = 2;
  shiftOut(data_pin, clk_pin, LSBFIRST, test);

  delay(5000);
}
```

I think there might be something wrong with my shiftIn/shiftOut command. It's actually the first time I'm using this.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

`shiftIn()` and `shiftOut()` are designed for communicating with different types of shift registers. These are typically external components which don't run code themselves, such as the 74HC595.

You can't use `shiftIn()` to read data that's been written using `shiftOut()`. The reason is that both functions try to act as the host in the communication -- i.e. the one that controls the clock line.

When you call `shiftIn()`, the clock line is pulsed each time it's ready to read a bit (i.e. it tells the shift register when to write). When you call `shiftOut()`, the clock line is pulsed each time it writes a bit (i.e. it tells the shift register when to read).

Neither one will respond to a clock line provided externally. The result is that your ATTiny's aren't synchronised so they won't be reading/writing at the same time.

A much simpler approach would be to setup a conventional serial connection between the two microcontrollers. You could do that either using [software](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) or [hardware](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial) serial. The only caveat is that the sender would need to ensure the receiver is up-and-running before it transmits anything. This could be done using some kind of handshake at startup -- one device repeatedly sends something until the other replies.